# CSS Arrows on LI

Tags: css

Trying to use the 
http://www.dinnermint.org/css/creating-triangles-in-css/
method to create an arrow

```
 _________________
 \                \
  \   Lorem        \
  /                /
 /________________/
```

using this  using only the

```
  <div id="sidebar">
        <ul>
            <li>Lorem</li>
            <li>Aliquam</li>
            <li>Vestibulum</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
```

I would prefer to not use images or jquery but just css

i have been able to use

```
    <div id="sidebar">
    <ul>
        <li>
            <div class="notch">
            </div>
            Lorem<div class="point">
            </div>
        </li>
        <li>
            <div class="notch">
            </div>
            Aliquam<div class="point">
            </div>
        </li>
        <li>
            <div class="notch">
            </div>
            Vestibulum<div class="point">
            </div>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
<style type="text/css">
    #sidebar ul { margin: 0 0 0 0; }
    #sidebar li { background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #336699; color: White; font-size: 25px; list-style: none outside none; margin: 25px 0; padding: 0 0 10px; text-align: center; vertical-align: middle; }
    .notch { float: left; border-color: Transparent Transparent Transparent White; border-style: solid; border-width: 20px; width: 0; height: 0; }
    .point { float: right; border-color: White White White Transparent; border-style: solid; border-width: 20px; width: 0; height: 0; }
</style>
```

but would rather not have all that design stuff in the html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Move div.point before text. This will work well.

```
 <div id="sidebar">
    <ul>
        <li>
            <div class="notch">
            </div>
            <div class="point">
            </div>
            Lorem
        </li>
        <li>
            <div class="notch">
            </div><div class="point">
            </div>
            Aliquam
        </li>
        <li>
            <div class="notch">
            </div>
            <div class="point">
            </div>
            Vestibulum
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: This doesnt actually change the way it renders or anything at all.  Nor does it reduce the amount of non semantic html.

Comment: have you try it? I've tested in FF, Chrome, IE7/8. What browser do you use?

Answer (score 2):

Use the following:

```
<ul style="list-style-type:none;">
<li>&rarr; List</li>
<li>&rarr; Etc.</li>
</ul>
```

This will show as:

→ List
→ Etc.